# How can I have localized messages when using Parsley.addAsyncValidator?

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

Let's say I add the following async validator:

```
Parsley.addAsyncValidator('availableEmail', function (xhr) {
    return 200 === xhr.status;
}, '/available-email');
```

and I use it on input like this:

```
<input
    id="email"
    type="email"
    name="email"
    data-parsley-remote
    data-parsley-remote-validator="availableEmail"
    data-parsley-remote-message="This email is unavailable"
>
```

Now this works fine and it shows me the error message if the validation fails. However, I can't find anyway to localize the error message.

Things I've tried:

1. Adding a `remote` property to one of the localization files:
   unfortunately, this makes that message global for all async validators, while I only want it to apply to the `available-email` validator.
2. Passing options object with a `messages` property to the `addAsyncValidator` method, that doesn't seem to work (unlike the `addValidator` method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need a custom "asyncValidator" here. The name isn't actually accurate, it's really only meant to be used to process results that aren't simply REST.

Best would probably to use a custom validator and call `$.ajax` yourself, like [in the first example here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/ajax.html).